# Hyper-V Powershell - add colons to MAC address

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have VM with multiple IP/MAC addresses

I'm using this code to get multiple IP/MAC addresses:

```
$vms=Get-VM | Where { $_.State –eq ‘Running’ } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 


 foreach($vm in $vms) {

    $out=Get-VMNetworkAdapter -vmname $vm | select VMName, MacAddress, IPAddresses

    $virtm=$out.VMName

    $ip=$out.IPAddresses



    if ($ip.Count -gt 1){

        foreach($i in $ip.Count) {
         if ($ip -match ':'){

         $ip = $ip | ?{$_ -notmatch ':'}

  }
}         
      $ip = $ip -join " "
      $virtm = ($virtm -split '\n')[0]
}
     else {
     $ip=$out.IPAddresses
       }

    $mac=$out.MacAddress

     if ($mac.count -gt 1) {

    $mac = $mac -join " "
        }

   foreach($m in $mac) {
     $mac=$m.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":")

    }

     Write-Output "$virtm, $ip, $mac"
```

This code works just fine, expect it can add columns to only first MAC address

**Current output:**

```
OAP80, 192.168.87.45 192.168.1.45, 00:15:5D:58:12:5E 00155D58125F
```

I want to add columns to all other MAC addresses for particular VM

**Desired output**

```
OAP80, 192.168.87.45 192.168.1.45, 00:15:5D:58:12:5E 00:15:5D:58:12:5F
```

I tried to add `:` before converting collection to to string

```
$mac=$out.MacAddress
  $mac=$mac.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":")
```

But getting:

```
Exception calling "Insert" with "2" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At line:35 char:6
+      $mac=$mac.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

Comment: you converted your `$Mac` collection into a string - ONE string - and then iterated thru ONE item. [*grin*] add your `:` BEFORE you merge the items into a single string.

Comment: You still need to iterate over  `$out.MacAddress` . Otherwise you try to insert your colon not into a string but into an array, which is not possible. Hence the exception.

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: I think you mean "colon" not "column".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short, you can do this to put colons in the Mac addresses and merge these as single string with a space as separator:

```
$mac = ($out.MacAddress | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":")
}) -join ' '

Write-Output "$virtm, $ip, $mac"
```

Comment: @xerks Thanks. P.S. As alternative to `Insert()`, you could use regex to add the colons inside the MAC address:
`($_ -split '([0-9a-f]{2})' -ne '') -join ':'`

Answer (score 3):

How about this?  "$&" means the whole match.  There's also negative lookahead to end of line, so a colon doesn't get put at the end.

```
$mac = echo 00155D58125F 00155D58125G 00155D58125H
$mac = $mac -replace '..(?!$)','$&:' 
$mac 

00:15:5D:58:12:5F
00:15:5D:58:12:5G
00:15:5D:58:12:5H
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `foreach` for `$mac`
Just use after(if mac in format XX-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx)

```
if ($mac.count -gt 1) {

    $mac = $mac -join " "
        }
$mac.Replace('-',':')
```

you can do this(if mac in format xxxxxxxxxxxx) : `$mac=$out.MacAddress|foreach{($_.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":"))-join " "}`

and can delete this:

```
if ($mac.count -gt 1) { $mac = $mac -join " " } foreach($m in $mac) { $mac=$m.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":") }
```

Comment: MAC address is in `00155D58125F` format, last line is useless

Comment: then you can do this :
`$mac=$out.MacAddress|foreach{($_.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":"))-join " "}`
and can delete this:
`if ($mac.count -gt 1) {

    $mac = $mac -join " "
        }

   foreach($m in $mac) {
     $mac=$m.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":")

    }`

Answer (score 0):

As Lee_Dailey has correctly pointed out: `$out.MacAddress` contains an array of strings. You want to go over each element and insert your colons before you join them up into a single string:

```
$mac = $out.MacAddress
$macWithColons = foreach ($m in $mac) 
{
    $m.Insert(2, ":").Insert(5, ":").Insert(8, ":").Insert(11, ":").Insert(14, ":")
}
$macWithColons -join " "
```